# Lazy tag is not working as supposed to be - Lazy is not lazy - initialized before used / called

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0, lazy-initialization

I am intending to use lazy initialization with a .NET core 6 WPF application with the following.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Lazy<List<int>> myNumbersList = new Lazy<List<int>>(Enumerable.Range(1, 99999999)
    .Select(x => x).ToList());

    List<int> myNumbersList2 = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 99999999)
    .Select(x => x).ToList());
}
```

[image]

[image]

They are both initialized even before the constructor of the WPF's MainWindow is called.

Isn't lazy supposed to be initialized whenever it is used?

Comment: Yes, the properties are initialized, but the lambda isn't executed unless you call .Value... Edit: oh, you don't pass an expression. You pass a value, calling the wrong constructor. Prepend the constructor parameter with `() =>`.

Comment: Lazy is initialized, you constructed it but the thing behind that, the List, isn't. You might want to check the IsValueCreated property on the Lazy instance to see yourself.

Comment: Generic types are not "tags" and C# is not HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Lazy` [ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-lazy-1-ctor(-0)) which accepts preinitialized value:

> `Lazy<T>(T)`
> Initializes a new instance of the Lazy class that uses a preinitialized specified value.
> **Parameters**
> value `T`
> The preinitialized value to be used.

You are probably looking for [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-lazy-1-ctor(system-func((-0)))) accepting `Func<T>` value factory:

> `Lazy<T>(Func<T>)`
> Initializes a new instance of the `Lazy<T>` class. When lazy initialization occurs, the specified initialization function is used.
> **Parameters**
> valueFactory `Func<T>`
> The delegate that is invoked to produce the lazily initialized value when it is needed.

```cs
Lazy<List<int>> myNumbersList = new Lazy<List<int>>(() => Enumerable.Range(1, 99999999)
   .Select(x => x).ToList());
```